# SMTP mailer and localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp

I am using wordpress locally on my laptop and I want to use smtp to send emails to users from the website page (not from the wordpress dashboard). I wrote the code in the page template and it tells me that the email was sent successfully but when I check the inbox and the junk or spam for the recipient email I do not find any emails received from the sender.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 
 
require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php'; 
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php'; 
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php'; 
 
$mail = new PHPMailer; 
 
//$mail->isSMTP();                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';        
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;               
$mail->Username = 'me@gmail.com';    
$mail->Password = 'gmail_password';    
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';           
$mail->Port = 465;                     
 

$mail->setFrom('me@gmail.com', 'Atheer'); 
$mail->addReplyTo('me@gmail.com', 'Atheer'); 
 

$mail->addAddress('ahood.q26@gmail.com'); 
 
 
 

$mail->isHTML(true); 
 
// Mail subject 
$mail->Subject = 'Email from Localhost by CodexWorld'; 
 

$bodyContent = '<h1>Hello</h1>'; 
$bodyContent .= '<p>This is Atheer<b>CodexWorld</b></p>'; 
$mail->Body    = $bodyContent; 
 

if(!$mail->send()) { 
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
} else { 
    echo 'Message has been sent.'; 
} 
?>
```

I am commenting the $mail->isSMTP(); becuase it was giving errors. I even tried the tls encryption and same problem it tells me send successfully while it is not sent.

Comment: And what error does `isSMTP()` throw? Calling that funciton tells phpmailer to send via SMTP.

Comment: This Error : Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: It's worth noting that "Not sent" isn't the same as "Not received". A lot can go wrong in between sending and receiving. e.g. even if PHP and your mailserver manage to send the email out successfully, if the email looks suspicious or unusual for any reason it can often be filtered out by the receiving mailserver, or another one along the route in between.

Comment: Enable the debug options from that link. Should point you in the right direction.